# Reasonable size task and title bar fonts on different high dpi displays

Tags: 16.04, display-resolution, cinnamon, hdpi

My laptop has a 15" Ultra HD screen, so to make things readable I used "Scale for menu and title bars" from Unity, this setting also affects cinnamon, the desktop manager I actually use. To clarify, I never really cared for a UHD resolution on my laptop, HD would have been fine, but my laptop simply has it.

Whenever I connect an external screen, I want to use a scaling optimized for that screen, as they are typically larger but have a lower resolution. For example, this is my desktop on an external screen.

[image]

As you can see, the title bar is really quite large and the task bar fonts are too large as well, especially considering the screenshot is displayed on a 34" screen. Usually when I reboot, the font-size  behavior is also different or inconsistent depending on which screens were connected when I powered on the laptop.

How can I set up screen specific settings to make sure that system fonts are reasonable on different screens? Is the scaling-setting also available in cinnamon, the "Display" configuration window seems very similar in Unity and cinnamon?